# I stored CaCO3 in a PET container and it went through the plastic and made the container brittle. What is the reaction?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I stored CaCO3 in a PET container and it went through the plastic and made the container brittle. What is the reaction ?

It also accumulate on the outside of other PET containers and made them brittle.

Does someone know what happened ?

Thank you
/Paul

Comment: That's not a thing that CaCO3 would do. Think of other suspects.

Comment: What do you mean by "CaCO3 went through the plastic" ? Have you observed a white powder on the outer surface of the bottle ? Are you sure that the powder so collected is calcium carbonate ? How long have you maintained this substance in the container, before observing this transformation ? Which test have you done to state that the container is brittle ? What do you mean with "other containers" ? Were these "other containers" also filled with calcium carbonate ? Where were these containers stored ? In a cupboard ? In a  basement ? With other chemicals ?